# ListView OnItemClickListener with a new Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, onitemclicklistener, sqliteopenhelper

I have the first activity with this code:

```
    lvlitems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Toast.makeText(BuscarNota.this, "Clicked"+ id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent= new Intent();
        intent.setClass(BuscarNota.this, Mostrar.class);
        intent.putExtra("id_nota", id);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
});
```

And then I have the second activity with this code:

```
EditText nota_input;
MiDB dbHandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar);
    nota_input= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtmostrar);

    int prePosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("id_nota", 0);
    Cursor c = dbHandler.notasbyid(prePosition);
    nota_input.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nota")));
}
```

But is not working... what I want is to show in the second activity in the EditText the data of "nota" that is a String.

This is the log:

> 06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): Process:
>   notasDeClase.example.notasdeclase, PID: 1469 06-09 15:23:55.340:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1469): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{notasDeClase.example.notasdeclase/notasDeClase.example.notasdeclase.Mostrar}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 06-09 15:23:55.340:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1469):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 06-09
>   15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 06-09
>   15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 06-09 15:23:55.340:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1469):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 06-09
>   15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 06-09
>   15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 06-09 15:23:55.340:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1469):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 06-09
>   15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 06-09 15:23:55.340:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1469): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):   at
>   notasDeClase.example.notasdeclase.Mostrar.onCreate(Mostrar.java:27)
>   06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 06-09
>   15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):   ... 11 more

Comment: `dbHandler` is what? null?

Comment: is where i have this:
 public Cursor notasbyid(int id){
  SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
  String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLA_NOTAS + " WHERE " + COLUMNA_ID + " = " + id + ";";
  Cursor c= db.rawQuery(query, null);
  
  if(c != null){
   c.moveToFirst();
  }
  return c;
 }

Comment: Try using `startActivity` instead of `startActivityForResult`. It doesn't look like you're passing any result to your `BuscarNota` Activity anyway.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): at notasDeClase.example.notasdeclase.Mostrar.onCreate(Mostrar.java:27)



What do we have at line 27 of Mostrar.java ?

Comment: doesnt work, but i still change it to startActivity

Comment: this: Cursor c = dbHandler.notasbyid(prePosition);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just solve it. thanks

```
EditText nota_input;
MiDB dbHandler;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrar);

    nota_input= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtmostrar);
    dbHandler = new MiDB(this, null, null,1);

    int prePosition =  (int) getIntent().getLongExtra("id_nota", 0);
    Cursor c = dbHandler.notasbyid(prePosition);
    nota_input.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nota")));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you instantiating dbHandler? Are you sure that you have properly initialized it? Can you post the generated SQL result for this? Are you getting any exception?

Some tips are:

- Make sure you are properly starting the dbHandler var;
- Make sure that the result of c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nota") is different of -1;
- Check out the generated sql in the LogCat and try to spot inconsistencies;

Comment: your onCreate method from the class Mostrar is not completing due to a nullPointerException that you are getting at line 27 (E/AndroidRuntime(1469): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 06-09 15:23:55.340: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): at notasDeClase.example.notasdeclase.Mostrar.onCreate(Mostrar.java:27) 06-09 15:23:55.340: ). What is in this line?

Comment: this: Cursor c = dbHandler.notasbyid(prePosition);

Comment: I believe your dbHandler variable is null. If it is not, check for possible causes of nullPointerException inside notasbyid method

Comment: is not null bc i have another activity that shows all my notes.. but what i cant is only show the one that i select in my listview

Comment: If you have instantiated this variable in another Activity, you will need to assign the recently created dbHandler in "Mostrar" again. When you declare a variable in a class null is assigned to it, it means, it points to nothing, you need to start it in order to do anything. I'm pretty sure now that this is your problem. dbHandler is null. You must assign a value to dbHandler (probably with a new statement or getXxx)

Comment: amm ok so how i can fix it?

Comment: Does MiDB has a public default constructor? If yes do dbHandle = new MiDB() before calling dbHandler.notasbyid(prePosition), otherwise call the custom constructor passing the parameters. Just like you did in the Activity in where it has worked